# What is one way to write about feeling someone's sadness?

Tags: creative-writing, narrative, emotions

For example:

> I sensed as if he became sad from the way he spoke after telling him
>   that I would go with her.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Threa, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  We aren't a site that does questions about rewording or critique.  As it stands now, your question is asking us to reword your example and is likely to be closed.  If you're asking something about the process of writing, please add to the question and explain what you're after.  Also check out other questions about [emotions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotions).

Answer (score 9):

This is a question of show vs tell.

It's easy to say that he became sad, but if you write it like this it also easly sounds cold and distant. If that's what you intend - good, keep it that way.

You can create a more emotional approach if you **show** his reaction, like

> I saw his eyes widening as I told him that I would go with her. He mumbled something that sounded slightly like 'okay'. But the way he avoided looking at me afterwards, fiddling around with the pencil he always carries in his pocket, gave me the sense that he might not be okay with it.

With the details of his reaction you can in a way control the emotional reaction of your reader because sadness shows different in each one of us. Some react angry, some apathetic, some immediately begin to cry and others don't show any immediate reaction but become quiet and withdrawn into themselfs if they have a moment without external stress.

Use this situation to build up the characters. How does the one being told react, how the one telling. It is a good opportunity to let the reader know something about both of them and their relationship.

Comment: +1, would do +2, if possible, for "It is a good opportunity to let the reader know something about both of them"

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to approach a character's emotions, each of which may be appropriate in context.

First, you can simply name the emotion. This is appropriate when their emotion is incidental to the main focus of the scene. It is also appropriate in cases where the character is giving no outward signs of the emotion. There is a difference between having and emotion and actively emoting, and people often hide their emotions, which is a significant aspect of their character and actions in many situations. If you have a scene were a bunch of soldiers stand guard over a comrade's coffin, for instance, you can't have them bursting into tears and sobbing their eyes out. They will be stoic in respect to both their friend and their uniform.

Second, you can describe the outward signs of the character's sadness, such as a long face or tears. This allows the reader to diagnose the characters sadness from the symptoms given. It also puts more of a focus on the character and their sadness, bringing it more to the center of the scene. But it also, for reasons explained above, tells you more about the character than simply that they had the emotion. It also tells you in what circumstances and by what means they allow themselves to express emotions, so you need to be careful to get that part of it right as well.

Third, you can make the reader intuit the emotion through the circumstances of the story. Most human being are good at intuiting others emotions. We don't need to see tears pouring down someone's face to know they are sad. If we know that they have been hoping for something and they don't get it, we know they are sad even if they are outwardly cheerful (as people often are, to mask their disappointments). Good writers exploit their reader's ability to intuit emotions by setting up the arc of the story and the arc of the characters so that when a particular event happens, we know how the characters feels because we feel it too. This is by far the most powerful way to write because here the reader is not merely diagnosing the emotions of another, they are participating in them sympathetically as we would with the emotions of a friend, and feeling them themselves.

Writing is about creating experiences. When it comes to emotions, you can create the experience of being told about an emotion, the experience of diagnosing an emotion, or the experience of having an emotion. Each of these is appropriate in its place (all three occur in real life as well) but the latter is by far the most powerful.

Answer (score 0):

> I sensed as if he became sad from the way he spoke after telling him that I would go with her.

Try describing the "I sensed".

What is your character observing exactly? Let he be our eyes looking at this person's sudden sadness.

In this situation, I would focus on your main character (the one observing here) and how he makes his realization bit by bit, sign by sign. "His voice was now softer, his words seemed to come out of his mouth with effort, now, like he was fighting within against thoughts I did not predict. His eyes no longer looking straight at me, no longer telling me of his enthusiasm, but looking within for the blurred, lost self-confidence." 
(Excuse my poor English, no native here).

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Giuseppe, glad you found us. Please check out our [tour] and [help].